# I want to scan folder path based on current date. If file doesn't exist send out email

Tags: powershell

I'm new here and need some help to enhance this script:

```
$path = "\\some\path"
if (!(test-path $path)) {
    Send-MailMessage  -To "car.one@outlook.com","car.two@gmail.com","car.three@yahoo.com" -From "Outbound@yahoo.com" -SmtpServer Smtp.office365.com -Subject "No file found" -BodyAsHtml -Body "No file was found at $path"  -UseSSL -Credential $cred
}
```

This is how the path look would look like `"\\Good\Morning\America`  there is a nested sub-folder with a date 20180114. There are files in that folder. I only want to scan for .abc and .def file extension.

If those extensions can't be found or the folder with today's date doesn't exist, send out an email notification.

If the folder and file do exist take no action.

Thanks in advance for everyone input.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet with the `-Include` parameter to figure if the files exist:

```
# Construct folder name and path from today's date
$TodaysFolderName = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$TodaysFolderPath = Join-Path '\\Good\Morning\America' $TodaysFolderName

# Fetch the required files
$Files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $TodaysFolderPath -Include *.abc,*.def)

# See if any of the relevant files were found
if($Files.Count -lt 1){
    Send-MailMessage ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mathias!    Can you add a line to scan if the subfolder if there is a zip, to do the same the process.

Comment: Just add it to the `-Include` list: `Get-ChildItem -Path $TodaysFolderPath -Include *.abc,*.def,*.zip`

Comment: Hi Mathias                                                                                                              Can you take a look at this and tell me if it makes sense. https://hastebin.com/utigapodir.pl